# How to pass list of objects between thread groups in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My first thread group parses a file and stores all the lines in a List. The second thread group should retrieve objects from the List one by one and send HTTPS request. Now the problem, how to make the list of objects  (not just a property value) between thread groups Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Beanshell Test Elements and `bsh.shared` namespace to [share variables across thread groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables)

In first thread group after parsing:

```
bsh.shared.myList = myList;
```

In second (or whatever thread group)

```
List myList = bsh.shared.myList;
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more scripting options.

If you use different scripting language (not Beanshell) - it is still possible to use `props` pre-defined variable which stands for JMeterProperties instance. JMeterProperties is basically an instance of [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) so you can store any object in there like:

In first thread group:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
//do what you need with the list
props.put("myList", myList);
```

In second thread group:

```
List myList = props.get("myList");
// do what you need with the list
```