# Passing object between JMeter threads

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

In my JMeter test plan, I need to make a single instance of 'ConcurrentHashMap' available to all sampler thread within the whole Test Plan. Note that, not just within a single thread group.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111019/608354) and [this](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#sharing_variables), I understand that to pass non-string object between threads in JMeter, I am supposed to put it in `props` global variable which is singleton for the entire test plan.

### The setup

Here's as far as I got. This is my overall test plan,

[image]

I have:

1. One [**Setup Thread Group**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) running  a single thread for one time only, running this JSR223 groovy script:

```
/* groovy */

def samples = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("samples", samples);
```

2. One **Sampling Thread Group**, running a number of thread for certain amount of time or a number of loops (depending on the load to be generated). Running this script:

```
/* groovy */

def samples = props.get("samples") as HashMap<String, Object>
if (samples == null) {
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Failed to retrieve sample list");
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500")
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
} else {
    // put sampe data along with a unique key into sample list
    samples.put(UUID.randomUUID(), new Object()); 
    // (1)
    // this line should print increasing number for each 
    // sampler putting data into the samplers list
    log.info("samples size: {}", samples.size())
}
```

3. And one [**Cleanup Thread Group**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) also running a single thread for one time only. Running this script:

```
/* groovy */

def samples = props.get("samples") as HashMap<String, Object>
if (samples == null) {
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Failed to retrieve list of samples");
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500")
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
} else {
    // (2)
    // This should print the total size of samples list one time
    log.info("samples size: {}", samples.size())
    // and the contents of sample list
    for (sample in samples) {
        log.info(sample.key)    
    }
}
```

### Expected outcome

What I am expecting is for (1) to print multiple times as much as the number of thread x iteration and on each print, it will show increasing count. And for (2) to print one time at test end to show the final size of sample lists and also print each of the unique id.

### Actual outcome

What I'm getting is that (1) will always sees the hashmap size to be '1' and (2) will always sees the hasmap size to be '0'.

And I'm not getting any sampling errors. All result are green (OK) meaning that `props.get("samples")` is never returning null. It's just that it seems to return not the instance I set on the setup phase.

### The question

Is there anything I missed in terms of method of passing non-string object between threads?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing an obvious logic action: writing your `samples` object back to the properties once you add a value into it in your **Sampling Thread Group**

Add the next line to the end of your JSR223 test element:

```
props.put('samples', samples)
```

and you should start getting the expected result.

You might find [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm) easier to use, it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Isn't ```props.get("samples")``` will return a reference to whatever object I put under "samples" key?

Comment: `int i = 1; int a = i; a += 5;` what is the value of `i`? Check out [Groovy Documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html) and [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) for more information.